# R DataTables do not search in column with html tags

Tags: html, r, datatables, shiny, dt

In my shiny app I render DataTable from DT package:

```
DT::renderDataTable( {

datatable(
  data = DT_frame, 
  selection = 'multiple', class = 'cell-border strip hover',
  escape = FALSE,  #po to, zeby dzialal: <a href=''></a>
  rownames = TRUE, 


  filter = list(position = "top",
                clear = F,
                plain = T),
  extensions = list(
    # "FixedHeader" = NULL ,
    # 'ColReorder' = NULL ,
    'Buttons' = NULL
  ),
  options = list(
    scrollX = TRUE,
    processing = T,
    searchHighlight = TRUE,
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = T),
    columnDefs = list(list(targets = cols2hide, visible = FALSE), list(type = 'html', targets = 4) ),
    # aoColumnDefs = list(list(sType = "html", aTargets = 4 )),
    # fixedHeader = TRUE,
    # colReorder = TRUE,
    dom = 'Blfrtip',
    # dom legend
    # p - NEXT/PREVIUS
    # i - Showing 1 to 10 of 106 entries
    # B - column visibility button
    # l - show n entries list
    buttons = c('colvis', 'csv')
  )
) %>% formatStyle(columns  = max_hash2_col_number, backgroundColor = '#CBFFB8') %>%
 formatStyle(max_hash2_col_number, cursor = 'pointer') }, server = T )
```

Column number 4 is clickable and includes HTML tags e.g.

```
<div id="44332211">33-ab-v4</div>
```

and I want to search in this column **but NOT IN html tags**. Reffering to [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) I added (as you can see above) to **columnDefs**:

```
list(type = 'html', targets = 4)
```

but it does not work and DataTables search in whole cell value. It should work like when I enter in search field: "44", DataTable **should not find**:

```
<div id="44332211">33-ab-v4</div>
```

Comment: Was this issue resolved? I'm dealing with this same issue and perhaps a solution has appeared in the 2 years since the accepted answer was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello in the page you link there is 
`Please note that if you are using server-side processing (serverSide) this option has no effect since the ordering and search actions are performed by a server-side script.`

Comment: Great! Thanks for help :)